# Three way database relationship

Tags: java, sql, spring, database

I am fairly new to database relationships, and im wondering if something like this is the best way to do this
A user should be connected to a list of images, those images contain metadata, as well as a link to a staff member, I need to be able to access the images from the staff member, as well as access the staff member from the image, and access the user from the image.

Basically in a nutshell the User needs a List of images, those images need to contain a staff member, and each staff member also needs a list of images

Just looking for the best relationships in my database for this.

Thanks

Comment: Those totally depend on the attributes and original relations

Comment: What do you mean @Eklavya

Comment: Without knowing your original entities  and attributes it's difficult to answer.

Comment: So a User needs to have a connection to a List of images, and each of those images needs to have a connection to a list of staff basically - each image needs to have metadata, hence the seperate entity

Comment: Update your post accordingly

Comment: Done,  thanks  for the tips, kinda new to stack overflow

Comment: This article is pretty good.  https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-onetomany-association-with-jpa-and-hibernate/

Answer (score 0):

If there is a single Staff member for each image you can just use these tables :

- User
- StaffMember
- Image (With an `ID` and the `Staff ID` as a foreign key)
- ImageByUser (With a `User ID` and an `Image ID` as foreign keys, with the `(User ID, Image ID)` being a primary Key and `Image ID` being unique ONLY IF an image can not be to multiple users)